# Bluetooth 5 & BLE throughput over multiple connections

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've been reading [this](https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-5-speed-maximum-throughput/) article on Bluetooth 5 & BLE maximum throughput. It provides data on maximum throughput across different devices and configurations. As far as I've understood, these measurements are defined by the connection between two devices and their respective data rates.

When establishing connections to more than one device, do these data rates apply to each connection independently? Or is the data rate shared between all of the connections?

For example: If I have a device with a maximum throughput of 1000kbps and connect it to two peripherals, will both connections have a throughput of 1000kbps? Or will it be split into two connections with 500kbps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Bluetooth chips I'm aware of only have one radio and one antenna. That means the connections are timeslotted. So if your connections use the 1Mbit/s PHY then the total throughput won't exceed 1Mbit/s.

How much each connection gets heavily depends on how the scheduler is implemented. If two connections have the same connection interval, a scheduler usually schedules a newly established connection to be allocated right after the first connection's connection events, which might lead to performance where the first connection can only send one or two packets per connection event and the second connection gets all remaining radio time.